# Highcharts 3D pie animation not rendering after setData

Tags: animation, highcharts, render, pie-chart

So i've been trying to solve this for a while now and i cannot seem to solve it.

Here is the example of the problem:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7B87c/4/)

```
chart.series[0].setData([
      ['Firefox', Math.random()*10],
      ['IE', Math.random()*10],
      ['Chrome', Math.random()*10]
], true);
```

I know that if i turn the animations off it works fine but i realy like the animation part :/

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is working already on github Highcharts version: http://jsfiddle.net/7B87c/5/